# Operations with functions

Tags: functions

I am having issues with a functions problem. I have checked with other friends and they have gotten a different answer than me. I would like if you could check my work for me. I have done this problem 10 times now, and I have gotten the same answer each time. I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

$g(x)=3x+5$

$f(x)=2x^3-x$

find $5g(-3)\cdot3f(-3)$

Here is what I have been doing:
$5(3(-3)+5)\cdot3(2(-3)^3-(-3))$

$5(-9+5)\cdot3(2(-27)-(-3))$

$5(-4)\cdot3(-54-(-3))$

$(-20)\cdot3(-51)$

$(-20)\cdot(-153)$

$3060$

Did I do anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why is f(-3)=2(-33)-3?

Comment: @gary I think that's just formatting for $2(-3)^3-(-3)$ which is consistent with the next line

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.  Also, when you write mathematics, you should make equalities explicit by using equals signs.  \begin{align*}5[3(-3) + 5] \cdot 3[2(-3)^3 - (-3)] & = 5(-9 + 5) \cdot 3[2(-27) - (-3)]\\ & = 5(-4) \cdot 3[-54 - (-3)]\\ & = (-20) \cdot 3(-51)\\ & = (-20) \cdot (-153)\\ &  = 3060\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the future, it would be a lot easier for us to understand your question if you use latex to typeset your equations.

Looking at your equation I am assuming you mean $g(x) = 3x + 5$, $f(x) = 2x^3 - x$, and the operation that you represented by the big black dot is multiplication; in that case, I got the same answer as you and I can't see any errors in your solution.

(It could be a case of you copying down a different question to that of your friends, and maybe that's why you have different solutions)